# Pass value through transition to the next template

Tags: ember.js

I have a "password request" page where a user enters their email to get a new password. Once the  email is entered there is a transition to a "password requested" page. I need to pass that email from the first page to the next hopefully using the tranistionToRoute. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

### Passed from this Controller:

```
App.ForgotPasswordController = Ember.Controller.extend
  actions:
    submit: ->
      ic.ajax.request(type: 'POST', url: 'api/v1/password_resets/', data: data).then (result)=>
        if result.status == 'ok'
          @transitionToRoute 'password-requested', email #something like this
```

### Passed to template of this Route:

```
App.PasswordRequestedRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (transition, email)->
    @set 'email', email
```

Comment: If 'password-requested' can take dynamic segments you should be able to pass that using transitionToRoute. You will be able to get it inside the model hook of the route.

Comment: Thanks for the help blessenm. I actually made it work with something like: @transitionToRoute 'password-requested', email and model: (email)-> email but I just felt that that was kinda weird and I don't like it showing the email in the url. Do you know how to hide the value from the url?

Comment: well another way is to set the value directly to the PasswordRequestedController and then go to that route. You can use 'needs' inside ForgotPasswordController to get access to the other controller. http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Comment: Can you still use needs if the routes aren't nested in the router? I thought you couldn't.

Comment: I think, needs will ask the container for an instance of the controller. If there is none, it will just create one for u.